# NGINX rewrite parameter to 'pretty' url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a URL where a user enters:

https://local.example.com/mh/526446841/mc90-c

The server serves from:

https://local.example.com/mh/526446841/?name=mc90-c

I can't seem to get it to work! I have tried:

```
rewrite ^/mh/(.*)/(.*)$ /mh/$1/?name=$2? last;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its present form it encourages a redirect loop, as the target URI still matches the *regular expression*.

I can think of three ways to break the loop:

1. Moving the `rewrite` statement into the `server` block, should make the `last` stop all rewrite processing.
2. Using the `rewrite` statement inside the same `location` block that processes both the source and target, means that the `last` can be changed to `break`.
3. Change the *regular expression* so that the target URI no longer matches:

   ```
   rewrite ^/mh/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /mh/$1/?name=$2? last;
   ```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.